# ASPX Website anchor link - orchard

Tags: asp.net, web, hyperlink, anchor, orchardcms

I made a Website with Orchard. Links are using no page names. A link can be something like 
"http://mywebsite/mainpage/subpage/product".

Now, on products page I wanted to link direct to an item. Normally I can use anchors to do this. 
Like
"item 99"
Item 99

The link to navigate to the item, normally is looking like this:
"http://mywebsite/mainpage/subpage/product/index.aspx?#item99"

But orchard has no index.aspx and when I use
"http://mywebsite/mainpage/subpage/product#item99"

it does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how the link should look like when using CMS/ASPX/ORCHARD ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<a href="#item99">item 99</a>

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: No, you don't missunderstood my question it seems.

Comment: It does. I just edited a page, made sure the text was long enough to not fit in my browser window, went into html view, added the code I gave above, published, hit http://localhost:30320/OrchardLocal/#foo and the browser scrolled to my anchor like it should.